# Deduced attributes of a LazyAttribute using Factory Boy

Tags: python, django, faker, factory-boy

Using [Factory Boy](https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy) and [Faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) in a Django project, i would like to create deduced attributes, meaning a method from `Faker` returns a set of values that are dependent on each other. These values will be utilized for  other attributes of the Factory Class.

Example:
The `location_on_land` [method](https://faker.readthedocs.io/en/master/providers/faker.providers.geo.html#faker.providers.geo.Provider.location_on_land) from `faker.providers.geo` returns a tuple of latitude, longitude, place name, two-letter country code and timezone (e.g. ('38.70734', '-77.02303', 'Fort Washington', 'US', 'America/New_York'). All values depend on each other, since the coordinates define the place, country, timezone, etc. Therefor i cannot use separated functions for the (lazy) attributes like `faker.providers.latitude`, `faker.providers.longitude`.

Is it possible to somehow access the return values from the lazy attribute to use them for other deduced attributes? Is there a better way to access the return values from `location_on_land` to use them on the other depending attributes
My Factory-Class looks like this:

```
# factory_models.py

class OriginFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    """Factory for Origin."""

    class Meta:
        model = models.Origin
        exclude = [
            "geo_data",
        ]
    
    # not working since not a lazy attribute
    # lat, lon, place, iso_3166_alpha_2, _ = fake.location_on_land()

    # desired outcome (not working)
    geo_data = factory.Faker("location_on_land")

    # attributes using the return values of `location_on_land` from lazy attribute (pseudo-code, desired)
    latitude = geo_data[...][0]
    longitude = geo_data[...][1]
    # foreign key
    iso_3166_alpha_2 = models.Country.objects.get(iso_3166_alpha_2=geo_data[...][2])
    ...
```

```
# models.py

class Origin(models.Model):
    origin_id = models.AutoField(
        primary_key=True,
        db_column="origin_id",
    )

    latitude = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        db_column="latitude",
    )

    longitude = models.FloatField(
        null=True,
        db_column="longitude",
    )

    region = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        blank=True,
        db_column="region",
    )

    iso_3166_alpha_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        to=Country,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        db_column="iso_3166_alpha_2",
    ...
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using [`factory.Params`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#simple-parameters), the resulting attribute is available on the first parameter on [`factory.LazyAttribute`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.LazyAttribute): the passed-in instance is a stub used to build the parameters for the actual model call.

In your case, I'd go with the following factory.

Note that the `geo_data` field is declared as a parameter (i.e not passed to the `models.Origin` constructor); but it is still available to other declarations on the factory.

```py
class OriginFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Origin

    class Params:
        geo_data = factory.Faker('location_on_land')

    latitude = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.geo_data[0])
    longitude = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.geo_data[1])
    iso_3166_alpha_2 = factory.LazyAttribute(
        lambda o: models.Country.objects.get(iso_3166_alpha_2=o.geo_data[3])
    )
```